# React modal container pattern with typescript and graphQL

Tags: reactjs, typescript, modal-dialog, graphql, graphql-codegen

Spectrum uses specific [pattern for modals](https://github.com/withspectrum/spectrum/tree/353bceb4435697e8414643ed81284d14a13e840b/src/components/modals) which I would like to replicate with typescript, graphQL and graphQL-codegen generated hooks.

Now what I currently have:

- GraphQL Client Schema

```
enum ModalType {
  LOGIN,
  SIGNUP,
}

type LoginModalProps{
  loginVal: String!
}

type SignupModalProps{
  signupVal: String!
}

extend type Query {
  openedModal: OpenedModal!
}

union ModalProps = LoginModalProps | SignupModalProps

type OpenedModal {
  modalType: ModalType!
  modalProps: ModalProps!
}
```

- GraphQL Query

```
export const GET_OPENED_MODAL = gql`
  query OpenedModal{
    openedModal @client{
      modalType,
      modalProps{
        ... on LoginModalProps {
          loginVal
        }
        ... on SignupModalProps {
          signupVal
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Code above is used by graphql-codegen for generating type safe query hook used below.

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginModal from '../containers/modals/LoginModal';
import SignupModal from '../containers/modals/SignupModal';
import { 
  useOpenedModalQuery, 
  ModalType, 
  LoginModalProps, 
  SignupModalProps 
} from '../../generated/graphql';

const ModalContainer: React.FC = () => {
  const { data } = useOpenedModalQuery();

  switch(data?.openedModal.modalType){
    case ModalType.Login:
      return <LoginModal {...data?.openedModal.modalProps as LoginModalProps}/>

    case ModalType.Signup:
      return <SignupModal {...data?.openedModal.modalProps as SignupModalProps}/>

    default: 
      return null;
  }
}

export default ModalContainer
```

Given modal declaration then looks as follows

```
import { LoginModalProps } from '../../../generated/graphql';

const LoginModal: React.FC<LoginModalProps> = ({
  loginVal
}) => {
```

I am new in this typed and graphQL world and it feels to me that it could be done better - especially the switch case statement that I had to use instead of the original object.
Is there some way how to preserve coupling between ModalType and ModalPropsType?
And is the code still safe with the `as` casting on ModalProps?